# Save multiple images to sd card

Tags: android

My project has 30 images in drawable & I would like to save/copy all these images to sd card on a button click. I'm using below code to save image to sd card but I don't want to copy paste this code 30 times to save all the images. So is there any better solution for this problem. Thanks

```
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.aurora);
        String fileName = "aurora.png";

        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File folder = new File(sd + "/Wallpaper Pack");
        folder.mkdir();

        File dest = new File(folder, fileName);
        try {
            FileOutputStream out;
            out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its very simple, create a array and loop it.

```
int[] drawablesArr = {R.id.name1, R.id.name2, ....}

for(int i=0l i<=drawablesArr.length; i++){
     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawablesArr[i]);
        String fileName = "image_"+ String.valueOf(i)+".png" ;

        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File folder = new File(sd + "/Wallpaper Pack");
        folder.mkdir();

        File dest = new File(folder, fileName);
        try {
            FileOutputStream out;
            out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: You have to change the filename on every iteration.

Comment: @Murtaza Hussain thanks for the code. I tried your code but was able to save only one image thanks to Ascorbin for pointing out necessary change. Now it works :) thank you guys. And is it possible to use my own filename instead of automated naming?

Comment: yes, everything is possible. create a model class and iterate it instead of simple int array

Comment: @Ascorbin answer is good. But my code should work. there is something you are missing. By the way glad your problem is solve. Async taks are specialized class to to task out of Main thread. You can try that too. its simple and recommended

Comment: @MurtazaHussain No no your code is absolutely working, I was talking about the code you posted earlier.

Comment: ohh yeah, thats 99% due to same filename. which causing it to replace with the last item in array.

Answer (score 1):

@Murtaza Hussain's answer is right but it is better to run such operations out of UI (main) Thread. So, you can use `ThreadPoolExecutor`:

```
// SaveThread.java
public class SaveThread implements Runnable {

    private int drawable;
    private String fileName;
    private Context context;

    public SaveThread(Context context, int drawable, String fileName) {
        this.drawable = drawable;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @override
    public void run() {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), drawable);

        File dest = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "WallpaperPack/" + fileName);
        dest.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

then inside your activity or in other components:

```
int core = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
ExecutorService executor =
        new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                core + 1,
                core * 2 + 1,
                60l,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()
                );

int[] drawables = {R.id.name1, R.id.name2, ....}

for(int drawable : drawables) {
    executor.execute(new SaveThread(getApplicationContext(), drawable, "image_"+ drawable +".png"));
}

executor.shutdown();
```

Comment: Since I'm new to android development it's really hard for me to understand your code, but anyway thanks for the code :)

Comment: @user2551070 OK, but be carefull, long-time running operations in UI Thread may cause ANR exception and it is different in different devices!

Comment: I'll try to understand & hopefully apply your approach in my app. Thanks for taking time to write the code snippet :)